# Hbase logs error while starting master

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using Hbase 0.94.8 version on a ubuntu based linux system. After following installation steps when i start

> HBASE_PATH$bin/start-hbase.sh

then console says

> starting master, logging to
>   /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/logs/hbase-psaha4-master-ubuntu.out

As its not throwing any error so i thought it should work properly.But when I open the "**logs/hbase-psaha4-master-ubuntu.log**" I can see it has thrown error as below:

> 2016-01-29 17:59:03,720 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start
>   master java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master:
>   class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMasterCannot
>   assign requ$
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:134)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:197)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.(LocalHBaseCluster.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:146)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2079) Caused
>   by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to
>   gladiator/10.32.137.144:0 : Cannot assign requested address
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.bind(HBaseServer.java:258)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Listener.(HBaseServer.java:482)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.(HBaseServer.java:1559)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.(WritableRpcEngine.java:252)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getServer(WritableRpcEngine.java:201)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getServer(WritableRpcEngine.java:55)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getServer(HBaseRPC.java:330)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getServer(HBaseRPC.java:319)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.(HMaster.java:306)

Can anyone suggest me why is this error and how can i solve the issue so that I can see the web UI for Hbase. Thanks

Comment: The piece that gives you some indication is this text "Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to gladiator/10.32.137.144:0 : Cannot assign requested address at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer.bind".. this [Hadoop Wiki link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException) gives some pointers on troubleshooting such errors.. it seems your configuration of HBase is trying to bind to a host:port (gladiator/10.32.137.144:0) that either does not exist or is already taken by another process..

Comment: can you paste your hbase-site.xml file?